# Words having weight near to minimum distance

Tags: coding-theory

I am studying the NP-Problem of the codes Syndrome Decoding. The formulation is show below.

Input: a binary matrix $H$ of dimension $r \times n$ and a bit string $S$ of length $r$.

Property: there exists a set of $w'$ columns of $H$ adding to $S$ (with $0 < w' 0 \leq w$).

I understand that this problem is hard if the code is unknow. But if the code was know, for example if it was a Goppa code and we know the support of the code and the polynomial that generates that code, There is some algorithm to find several words with the same weight and the same syndomre?

Comment: You may benefit from a study/search of Madhu Sudan's list decoding algorithm. He designed it for Reed-Solomon codes, but it has been extended to algebraic-geometry codes (aka Goppa codes) by Kötter, Vardy and their students. The algorithm gives a list of codewords within a certain Hamming distance that is larger than the guaranteed error-correcting capability (so the list may contain more than one codeword). Note: the algorithm still places an upper bound to the Hamming distance from the received word. Those papers have the formula.